# How to compare cell values of two different DataFrames in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrames:

**Person_df**

```
Name  Emplid  Country

    0  DK     123    India

    1  JS     456    India

    2  RM     789    China

    3  MS     111    China

    4  SR     222    China
```

**Target_df**

```
Country Category    Target

    0   India   Marketing   Reduce spend by $xy.

    1   India   R&D         Increase spend by $dd.

    2   India   Infra       Reduce spend by $kn.

    3   China   Marketing   Increase spend by $eg.

    4   China   R&D         Increase spend by $cb.

    5   China   Infra       Reduce spend by $mn.
```

My aim is to create a third DataFrame based on the country of each person, which would look like this:

**Individual_df**

```
TargetID    Category    Target

    DK12301     Marketing   Reduce spend by $xy.

    DK12302     R&D         Increase spend by $dd.

    DK12303     Infra       Reduce spend by $kn.

    JS45601     Marketing   Reduce spend by $xy.

    JS45602     R&D         Increase spend by $dd.

    JS45603     Infra       Reduce spend by $kn.

    RM78901     Marketing   Increase spend by $eg.

    RM78902     R&D         Increase spend by $cb.

    RM78903     Infra       Reduce spend by $mn.

    MS11101     Marketing   Increase spend by $eg.

    MS11102     R&D         Increase spend by $cb.

    MS11103     Infra       Reduce spend by $mn.

    SR22201     Marketing   Increase spend by $eg.

    SR22202     R&D         Increase spend by $cb.

    SR22203     Infra       Reduce spend by $mn.
```

Basically I have to take a person from Person_df, match his/her country with country mentioned in Target_df and then assign each of this target to this person(and store in Individual_df).

Problem is, I am new to python and can't really figure out how to carry out this comparison of country.

I wrote the code below:

```
for index, row in Person_df.iterrows():

     

        for index1, row1 in Goals_df.iterrows():

            If Person_df['country'] == Person_df['country'] : #I know this is incorrect

                data = [] 

                #populate data[] with selected values for one person.

                #append data[] to Individual_df
```

I need help on couple of points here:

1) How really I can perform the comparison here for country of each person.

2) Even if I know how to compare, the code I wrote is not at efficient as I am doing loads of unnecessary iterations here. Any pointers how can I improve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Thasin, Thanks for the solution. I am trying this out. In origional data there are more number of columns and more conditions for the final dataset, so its taking some time. Currently trying to rectify 'Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)'! Will update as soon as I am done with it :)

Comment: yeah sure. Good luck :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
Individual_df = pd.merge(Person_df, Target_df2, on=['Country'], how='left')
Individual_df['TargetID'] = Individual_df['Name'] + df3['Emplid'].astype(str) + ((df3.groupby('Emplid').cumcount() + 1).astype(str).str.zfill(2))
Individual_df = Individual_df[['TargetID', 'Category', 'Target']]
print Individual_df
```

Output:

```
   TargetID   Category                  Target
0   DK12301  Marketing    Reduce spend by $xy.
1   DK12302        R&D  Increase spend by $dd.
2   DK12303      Infra    Reduce spend by $kn.
3   JS45601  Marketing    Reduce spend by $xy.
4   JS45602        R&D  Increase spend by $dd.
5   JS45603      Infra    Reduce spend by $kn.
6   RM78901  Marketing  Increase spend by $eg.
7   RM78902        R&D  Increase spend by $cb.
8   RM78903      Infra    Reduce spend by $mn.
9   MS11101  Marketing  Increase spend by $eg.
10  MS11102        R&D  Increase spend by $cb.
11  MS11103      Infra    Reduce spend by $mn.
12  SR22201  Marketing  Increase spend by $eg.
13  SR22202        R&D  Increase spend by $cb.
14  SR22203      Infra    Reduce spend by $mn.
```

Explanation:

1. perform left join with Person_df and Target_df
2. then create TargetID based on Name and Employee Id with cumcount of emp id
3. extract required columns

**As User requested to get rows by for loop:**

```
unique_countries=df1['Country'].unique().tolist()

for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    if row['Country'] in unique_countries:
        print row.values
        //do operation
```

Explanation:

1. find unique element of Person_df
2. iterate Individual_df through for loop
3. check if country present or not in unique element(countries)
   if present perform desired opearion.

Comment: Hi Thasin, It worked perfectly! I am new to python was not yet aware about dataframe join. Just wondering, lets say these join options does not exist and we are forced to use good old for loop for data comparison(like I was trying to do)...then how would we compare these two values in different dataframes?

Comment: @AnshulRai - I didn't unserstand your question. Do you want to compare two different columns with for loop?

Comment: yes. Wanted to compare column value of one data frame with the column value of another(first row has 'country' column as 'India' in first data frame, so wanted to go through country column of the another dataframe and select the rows where column value is 'India'. Now I know this is not at all needed as we can simply join on common column. Still wanted to know if we can achieve this without join or not(just for learning purpose).

Comment: Thanks again Thasin for the second solution!

Comment: @AnshulRai - You are always welcome. feel free to raise a python or pandas based question. in case of any help you could contact me through my e-mail.